# Signing OneNote for Windows into second account breaks the first one

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

In OneNote for Windows (Office365) I signed into 2 work accounts on different domains (let's call them A and B).

Now OneNote is complaining about "Account Error" on account A but when I click continue it loads login page from domain B with prepopulated account from domain A.

I can either continue in which case this will fail because user A won't be found in domain B or I can "Use another account" but that is still limited to domain B.

Couple of things I tried that didn't help:

1. Removing account B
2. Deleting `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\OneNote`
3. Deleting `%AppData%\Microsoft\OneNote`
4. Removing both accounts then only adding account A

   - this one works initially but after few minutes reports account error and presents login form of domain B

I'm assuming this is a bug in OneNote (also present in other Microsoft apps btw) where they share cookies between sign-in webviews from different accounts.

How can I fix it. Where is OneNote keeping its webview cookies?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - This question absolutely would NOT be within scope at Webapps SE and is absolutely within scope here.